# Remove space of checkbox if it does not exist

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a listView populated with the help of a CustomAdapter.

I make a test while retrieving the values from my db.

One of the rows if 'Homework'. If homework = 1, then I show a CheckBox in the beginning of the line of my listView. But if it's 0 , I dont show anything. But I'd like to move all the text after the checkbox to the left. in my list_row.xml I declared a checkbox, so if homework is 0, i just setVisibility to INVISIBLE on my checkbox.

I can't post images, so I'll give an example :

if homework is 1 , my listView is like this :

```
Checkbox - Date of creation - Title
```

if Homework is 0, my row of the listview is like this :

```
         - Date of creation - Title
```

So you can see that there will have an empty space if Homework is 0. How can I change that so it stays like this:

```
-Date of creation - Title
```

Thank you !And tell me if you need the code my CustomAdapter please

@UPDATE-my customadapter

```
`public class CustomAdapterJalons extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private Context appContext;
private int layout;
private Cursor cr;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapterJalons(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.layout = layout;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.cr = c;
}



@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    final int position = cursor.getPosition();

    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    int devoir = cursor.getInt(3);
    int evaluation = cursor.getInt(4);
    int importance = cursor.getInt(5);
    int fait = cursor.getInt(10);
    final CheckBox cbdevoir = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.CBDevoir);
    final TextView couleur = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TVCouleurImportance);

    if(importance==0)
    {
        couleur.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff8080"));
    }
    if(importance==1)
    {
        couleur.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
    }
    if(importance==2)
    {
        couleur.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4d0000"));
    }

    if (fait == 1) {
        cbdevoir.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        cbdevoir.setChecked(false);
    }


    cbdevoir.setVisibility(devoir ==1? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);`
```

my list_row.xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:id="@+id/item_root"
android:weightSum="1">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CBDevoir"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:checked="false"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_branche_cours"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="English"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_trait"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" - "
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="106dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_designation"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="122dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Reading"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TVCouleurImportance"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="281dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

`

Comment: set your check box visibility to "GONE" instead of invisible

Comment: does it matter the visibility I set at the beginning on my list_row.xml ?

Comment: why did you use extra textview here you can directly use checkbox.setText("") like this

Comment: the textView has nothing to do with the checkbox... and I want to hide the checkbox, not removing the text of it..

Comment: try as Demo Mail suggested setVisibility to "Gone"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of view you're using you can always remove the view from the layout.

For example you could take a linear layout and call .removeView(View) to remove the checkbox entirely instead of just making it invisible. Just remember that if you're recycling views you'll want a way to add it back in later!

I recommend the viewholder pattern.
 https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

When you set view to gone, it doesn't take any space for that layout, while setting it to invisible does.

Comment: does it matter the visibility I set at the beginning on my list_row.xml ?

Comment: @Dom you need to set it dynamically in your adapter's `getView` method. `checkBoxView.setVisibility(isHomeWord == 1? View.Visible: View.Gone)`. Setting the visibility in your list_row.xml only grants the initialization visibility.

Comment: @Dom what's the problem?

Comment: it doesnt change anything when I set gone

Comment: @Dom what's the problem? Does your checkbox view still take up extra space? Try to remove your two if clauses at the end, and use `cbdevoir.setVisibility(devoir == 1? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);` Also remove your `Visibility` property row of your CheckBox view in your list_row.xml

Comment: yes it still takes the extra space even if I write the code u told me..

Comment: it's weird because if I say that even if homework is 0, the checkbox is still visible and it worked, but when I write GONE it does not work..

Comment: If you use code you posted above, your CheckBox should be set to GONE for sure if homeword is 0. It's possible that your other views (maybe TextView with empty Text) are taking up spaces, or maybe the value of margin/padding of other views are too big.

Comment: I've deleted the TextView with empty space just to test and it does not change anything ..

Comment: My last suggestion for today is that change `ConstraintLayout ` to `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation.  Add `Checkbox - Date of creation - Title' three views into your linearlayout. Try to not add any margin/padding into any view just for testing purposes. Refer to this link if needed https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter I will get back to you tmrw if you still have this problem

Comment: @Dom did you get your problem fixed?

Comment: Hello, you were right ! Changing to a LinearLayout fixed the problem, thank you !!! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you set the visibility of a view to inivisible it becomes invisible but occupy the space where it is used so set visibility ot Gone to free the space occupied by the view.Use below line of code in getview method of your adapter

```
  if(devor==1){
     if (fait == 1) {
        cbdevoir.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        cbdevoir.setChecked(false);
    }
     }else{
cbdevoir.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Do something like this

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxId);
        cb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(getHomeWork()==1){
          cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       
        }
        return rowView;
    }
```

setVisibility have Three different options

1. **View.VISIBLE** - This show the view in screen if it is gone
2. **View.GONE** - This will hide the view and your other content take place of this view
3. **View.INVISIBLE** - This will hide view but other view will not take the place of this view (means space is remains as it is of that view)